# C++ arrays const char

Tags: c++, arrays

Hello I have this very simple function:

```
    void sample(int data[])
    {
         const int DataSize = data[sizeof(data)] // Last int in array contains data size
         int DataTable[DataSize] = {}; // error here must have a constant value
    }
```

How can i make an empty array table the size of my last int in array?

Comment: What's `code` actually? What is you verbatim error message? Where's your [MCVE]()http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: Array sizes must be compile-time constants. `data` is not. Try using a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: πάνταῥεῖ hello sorry code is supposed to be data, updated it.
@NeilKirk I've read that using vectors is the solution but exactly how?

Comment: `std::vector<int> DataTable(DataSize);`

Comment: `data[sizeof(data)]` This looks wrong. What do you think it does?

Comment: @NeilKirk I thought it would return the last int inside of data like this:

foo[] = {1, 2,3}
foo[sizeof(foo)] should return 3 correct?

Comment: @zenith thanks a lot, but can i loop through values inside the vector just as i would in an array? if so this would be the perfect solution and i can mark it as answered :)

Comment: @CheekyLewb Yes you can loop through a vector with range-based for-loop, normal for-loop, or iterators, up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Neil Kirk mentioned, raw array sizes must be compile-time constants. `DataSize` is not a compile-time constant, it's a run-time constant.

Use an [**`std::vector`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), its size can be determined at run-time.

---

Additionally, `sizeof(data)` returns the size of `data` in **bytes**, not the number of elements in it. You need to pass the size of `data` as a parameter to be able to use it inside the function.

```
void sample(int data[], int size)
{
     const int DataSize = data[size - 1];
     // size - 1 is the index of the last element in data.

     std::vector<int> DataTable(DataSize);
     // DataTable now contains DataSize ints, all initialized to 0.
}
```

---

Or, you could just turn `data` into a vector too which would simplify things a lot:

```
void sample(const std::vector<int>& data) // Pass data as a const reference.
{
     const int DataSize = data.back();
     // The `back` function accesses the last element in a vector.
     ....
}
```